# How to calculate OHLCV data from tick data in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, ohlcv

I have some tick data store in influxdb, protocol line like below,
(Note: lastPrice is realtime price at that time, totalVolume is cumulative trade quantity from the begining of the day)

```
tick,contract=FU2301 lastPrice=10.2,totalVolume=100
tick,contract=FU2301 lastPrice=10.1,totalVolume=110
tick,contract=FU2301 lastPrice=10.3,totalVolume=150
...
tick,contract=FU2301 lastPrice=9.8,totalVolume=290
```

I am trying to calculate 1 minus OHLCV from tick data. (Note: the volume here is the trade quantity of every minus)

```
time measurement contract open high low close volume
----
xxxx tick        FU2301   10.2 10.3 9.0 9.3   10
xxxx tick        FU2301   10.2 10.3 9.1 9.2   40
xxxx tick        FU2301   10.1 10.4 9.0 9.1   20
```

so my flux script like below, but it didn't work expected.

```
data = from(bucket: "mk_data_test")
  |> range(start: -12h, stop: now())
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "tick")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["contract"] == "FU2301")
  |> window(every: 1m)

volumeData = data |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "totalVolume")
priceData = data |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "lastPrice")

max = priceData |> max() |> set(key: "_field", value: "max")
min = priceData |> min() |> set(key: "_field", value: "min")
open = priceData |> first() |> set(key: "_field", value: "open")
close = priceData |> last() |> set(key: "_field", value: "close")
// this expression didn't work excepted
volume = volumeData |> first() |> difference() |> set(key: "_field", value: "volume")

union(tables: [max, min, open, close, volume])
  |> pivot(rowKey: ["_start"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you struggled with the volume dataset's row number? By default, "for each input table with n rows, difference() outputs a table with n - 1 rows."

If you want to align volume dataset with max, min, open and close, you could turn on the **keepFirst** flag:

```
volume = volumeData |> difference(keepFirst: true) |> set(key: "_field", value: "volume")
```

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.x/stdlib/universe/difference/#keepfirst).

Comment: I have tried to add **keepFirst**, but it still prints nothing. What I want is take the first totalVolume in every 1 minus, and calculate difference of them.

Comment: You might need to get the first value and assign it to a variable then put it this value in the fill function since keepFirst will assign a null value to the first record.

Comment: Yes, you are right, difference() just produce n-1 records unless I add keepFirst argument and using a value replace the default null value. And I found difference function can only work within a window, can't work across different window. I should unwindw before using difference function

`
volumeData |> first() |> window(every: inf) |> difference(keepFirst: true) |> .... 
`